# Selenium failed to send_keys on Datepicker field using Python

Tags: python, selenium, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I want to send_keys to a readonly datepicker, I failed to input the date.
Here is the[link](https://epaper.oeeee.com/epaper/A/html/2018-02/06/node_2637.htm)
I try to remove the readonly first, clear, and send_keys.

```
url="https://epaper.oeeee.com/epaper/A/html/2018-02/06/node_2637.htm"
driver.get(url)
d=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute(\"readonly\")', d)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').clear()
d.send_keys('2018-02-02')
d.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

[image: date badget image]

Could anyone tell me why?

Many thanks

Comment: clear() does not work at all on some kinds of fields. did you try doing             
   element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
   element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I don't think it's read-only, I can regularely click on it, without changing anything. then I don't think that you can clear and set it again as you might want. But there are quite a few solved datepicker problems, I will link you some with their respective solutions below:

[How to change the date of a hidden element of a Datepicker using setAttribute method and Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064715/how-to-change-the-date-of-a-hidden-element-of-a-datepicker-using-setattribute-me?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000)
[Selenium calendar picker: I can click manually but Selenium cant click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64660455/selenium-calendar-picker-i-can-click-manually-but-selenium-cant-click?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000)
[How do I click on active day on date picker using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516795/how-do-i-click-on-active-day-on-date-picker-using-selenium-python?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C0.0000)

Comment: Dear Norayr, it's the read-only and it is not a hidden element. ```<input type="text" class="datepicker" readonly="readonly" data-date="2018-02-06">```.

Comment: That doesnt matter, i showed a few links where its solved how to use a date picker, quite sure one of them will work

Comment: I tried those links you provided, but it did not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery Datepicker

> The [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is tied to a standard form `<input>` field. Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.

If you observe the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) of the [web application](https://epaper.oeeee.com/epaper/A/html/2018-02/04/node_2478.htm) it uses **jQuery**

```
"jquery": "/epaper/js/lib/jquery/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"
```

Now as per the HTML of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139):

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" readonly="readonly" data-date="2018-02-04">
```

Though the datepicker field is an `<input>` field, on click it calls the `jQuery` based **`datepicker`** class which doesn't accept any **text** input. Hence `send_keys()` fails to send any character sequence to the `<input>` field.